# changing color or tool-tip in one go

Tags: qt, qt5

I have made one large project using Qt designer which has .ui, .cpp, .h files.
Now I want to add colors and tool-tip to pushbuttons of all .ui files in one go or some easy way, because it WOULD BE VERY DIFFICULT TO GO THROUGH ALL .ui files and change color of each pushbuttons.
Is there anyway I can do this?
If you are not sure you can share your ideas.
Please.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) to customizing your widgets across your application. For example, to set background color for all `QPushButtons` in your application add such code:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: yellow }");
```

[Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use suitable editor with "Find and replace in files", or *sed/perl/awk* if you prefer command line. Use this on the .ui files (they are XML). First figure out the search which finds you the right places, and then do the replacement. If you need to replace just a specific string (defining the color), then you don't even need regexps.

Warning: The .ui files are not really meant to be hand-edited. Therefore it is fairly easy to break them so that Designer can no longer work on them. But there's no magic in this, they're just text files which can be edited, Designer just expects them to be exactly like it wants them and doesn't allow for mistakes often introduced by hand editing. Just be sure to change only the color value string and nothing else, and have an unedited backup (ie. version control), and you should be fine.

Note that Qt Creator refuses to edit .ui files as text, because they are so easy to break by hand-editing, so you probably want to use some other editor (Notepad++ is a common free Windows alternative).

---

However, I would recommend first trying with style sheets, as said in the other answer. Only if that proves to be impractical, then you should consider this option. The big benefit of style sheets is, if you need to do another change, then it's much less work, than doing another search-replace.

Comment: Although that's a valid option, I stronly recommend using Qt Style Sheets as pointed out by the other answer.

Comment: @maxik I agree, but switching to using style sheets instead of properties might be quite a big undertaking too. As I understand it, using style sheets and using other ways to style the app don't always mix too well. In that case just changing the color in the .ui files might be the practical option. Anyway, edited my answer a bit to match this.